# extracting unique values between 2 sets/files

Tags: linux, perl, bash, scripting, command-line

Working in linux/shell env, how can I accomplish the following:

text file 1 contains:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

text file 2 contains:

```
6
7
1
2
3
4
```

I need to extract the entries in file 2 which are not in file 1. So '6' and '7' in this example.

How do I do this from the command line?

many thanks!

Comment: Is it homework? If positive, please tag it as so.

Comment: what is the separator of values?

Comment: good catch! each value is on its own line; so newline sep.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++; next} !($0 in a)' file1 file2
6
7
```

Explanation of how the code works:

- If we're working on file1, track each line of text we see.
- If we're working on file2, and have not seen the line text, then print it.

Explanation of details:

- `FNR` is the current file's record number
- `NR` is the current overall record number from all input files
- `FNR==NR` is true only when we are reading file1
- `$0` is the current line of text
- `a[$0]` is a hash with the key set to the current line of text
- `a[$0]++` tracks that we've seen the current line of text
- `!($0 in a)` is true only when we have not seen the line text
- Print the line of text if the above pattern returns true, this is the default awk behavior when no explicit action is given

Comment: sweet! this works great but what if the values are each on a separate line, not separated by space as in my example (i actually had them on a new line but SO formatted them on the same line)?

Comment: @mark my code will work for both cases, but if each number is on a separate line, you can completely remove the `RS="[ \n]"` to make the code shorter.  Also, welcome to SO.

Comment: @mark by the way, to prevent SO from formatting your code, highlight it then either press CTRL+K or click the `{ }` icon. I edited your question already with this change.

Comment: @SiegeX, consider adding some spaces into the code sample, please. Snippet is hard to understand for lacking of them. One may think that you are playing code golf or your spacebar is broken)

Comment: @Rorick that's what the `Edit` button is for, if you think you have a better way to represent it that others can benefit from feel free to make the edit and put it up to a vote

Comment: Just for the record, this technique though it works will create `a[$0]` mem position for all second file entries that do not exist in first file. If the second file has a million of lines this solution is not the best. `$0 in a` method on the other hand, checks for existance  but does NOT create an extra mem position for second file entries.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou The main reason I don't use `$0 in a` is because order is *not* guaranteed to be preserved and that is important more often than not.

Comment: When using this in scripts, make sure to first check that `file1` is not empty (0 bytes long), because if it is, you will get an empty result instead of the expected contents of `file2`. (Cause: `FNR==NR` will apply to `file2` then.)

Comment: @SiegeX Why is order not guaranteed to be preserved with `$0 in a`?

Comment: @Cole you're right, it doesn't.  I must have been thinking about the `for(i in a)` construct back in '17.  Thanks for keeping me honest, I will update the answer.

Comment: @SiegeX Thanks!  And `for(i in a)` not preserving order just sounds like an accident waiting to happen...

Answer (score 30):

Using some lesser-known utilities:

```
sort file1 > file1.sorted
sort file2 > file2.sorted
comm -1 -3 file1.sorted file2.sorted
```

This will output duplicates, so if there is 1 `3` in `file1`, but 2 in `file2`, this will still output 1 `3`.  If this is not what you want, pipe the output from `sort` through `uniq` before writing it to a file:

```
sort file1 | uniq > file1.sorted
sort file2 | uniq > file2.sorted
comm -1 -3 file1.sorted file2.sorted
```

There are lots of utilities in the GNU coreutils package that allow for all sorts of text manipulations.

Comment: Good call on these utilities. You can combine this to a much simpler form and remove the need for temp files: `comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`  I still prefer `awk` only because it runs a single process instead of 3 as it doesn't require sorted files.  This can make a big difference on large files.

Comment: `join` can also be used for this.

Comment: @SiegeX - I personally prefer the version with 3 commands - that way if I need to tweak on of the commands (or for example, get updated file1) I don't need to re-run the WHOLE thing; which can be a benefit for really large files. Also, the syntax you provided sounds like bash, it may not work on other shells (/bin/sh or csh derivatives)

Answer (score 14):

I was wondering which of the following solutions was the "fastest" for "larger" files:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++}FNR!=NR && !a[$0]{print}' file1 file2 # awk1 by SiegeX
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next}!($0 in a)' file1 file2          # awk2 by ghostdog74
comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
join -v 2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
grep -v -F -x -f file1 file2
```

Results of my benchmarks in short:

- Do not use `grep -Fxf`, it's much slower (2-4 times in my tests).
- `comm` is slightly faster than `join`.
- If file1 and file2 are already sorted, `comm` and `join` are much faster than awk1 + awk2. (Of course, they do not assume sorted files.)
- awk1 + awk2, supposedly, use more RAM and less CPU. Real run times are lower for `comm` probably due to the fact that it uses more threads. CPU times are lower for awk1 + awk2.

For the sake of brevity I omit full details. However, I assume that anyone interested can contact me or just repeat the tests. Roughly, the setup was

```
# Debian Squeeze, Bash 4.1.5, LC_ALL=C, slow 4 core CPU
$ wc file1 file2
  321599   321599  8098710 file1
  321603   321603  8098794 file2
```

Typical results of fastest runs

```
awk2: real 0m1.145s  user 0m1.088s  sys 0m0.056s  user+sys 1.144
awk1: real 0m1.369s  user 0m1.324s  sys 0m0.044s  user+sys 1.368
comm: real 0m0.980s  user 0m1.608s  sys 0m0.184s  user+sys 1.792
join: real 0m1.080s  user 0m1.756s  sys 0m0.140s  user+sys 1.896
grep: real 0m4.005s  user 0m3.844s  sys 0m0.160s  user+sys 4.004
```

BTW, for the awkies: It seems that `a[$0]=1` is faster than `a[$0]++`, and `(!($0 in a))` is faster than `(!a[$0])`. So, for an awk solution I suggest:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=1;next}!($0 in a)' file1 file2
```

Comment: Excellent benchmarking, results, and optimizations. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

How about:

```
diff file_1 file_2 | grep '^>' | cut -c 3-
```

This would print the entries in file_2 which are not in file_1. For the opposite result one just has to replace '>' with '<'. 'cut' removes the first two characters added by 'diff', that are not part of the original content.

The files don't even need to be sorted.

Answer (score 6):

with grep:

```
grep -F -x -v -f file_1 file_2
```

Comment: This leads to wrong results, as can be shown if a . (dot) is added to file_1. `grep -F -x -v -f file_1 file_2` is indeed correct.

Comment: @xebeche: Thx! Corrected the code line according to your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

here's another awk solution

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next}(!($0 in a))' file1 file2
6
7
```

Comment: What are the rules where you can use `()` in lieu of `{}`? I'm assuming this isn't a gawk'ism because you tend to use `gawk` when that's the case.

Comment: as you know, awk syntax consists of `/pattern/{action}`. `((!$0 in a))` is the "pattern" part. `{action}` is printing by default. Its like you can do `NR==1` (for example).

Comment: I guess I'm more curious about the double set of parens, why isn't `(!$0 in a)` sufficient?  Btw, if you prefix your comment with `@username` then username actually gets a notification that there is a comment to them pending, otherwise they won't.  The `@username` prefix isn't necessary only if you are the person who wrote the question and/or answer people are commenting on.  So technically I didn't need to do it for this comment to you.

Comment: @SiegeX, no the double parenthesis doesn't matter in this case. Its a habit of mine. the double parenthesis is needed though, if there are more conditions.

Comment: This solution is the only one who checks existance in array without creating an extra mem position.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file1 file1 file2 | sort | uniq -u
6
7
```

> uniq -- report or filter out repeated lines in a file
>
> ... Repeated
> lines in the input will not be detected if they are not adjacent, so
> it may be necessary to sort the files first.
>
> ```
> -u      Only output lines that are not repeated in the input.
> ```

Print file1 twice to make sure all entries from file1 are skipped by `uniq -u` .

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file1 file2 | sort -u > unique
```

Comment: `sort -u` will keep one occurrence of each duplicate.  In the question example, `1`, `2`, and `3` would still be printed in addition to the desired values of `6` and `7` .

Answer (score -1):

If you are *really* set on doing this from the command line, [this site](http://www.vectorsite.net/tsawk_3.html#m2) (search for "no duplicates found") has an `awk` example that searches for duplicates.  It may be a good starting point to look at that.

However, I'd encourage you to use Perl or Python for this.  Basically, the flow of the program would be:

```
findUniqueValues(file1, file2){
    contents1 = array of values from file1
    contents2 = array of values from file2
    foreach(value2 in contents2){
        found=false
        foreach(value1 in contents1){
            if (value2 == value1) found=true
        }
        if(!found) print value2
    }
}
```

This isn't the most elegant way of doing this, since it has a O(n^2) time complexity, but it will do the job.