# Using a variable in sed search pattern when the value of the variable contains square brackets

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed

What I'm trying to do is check that a file has been created. The best way I can think to do this is by listing the files before hand, listing them afterwards, deleting the before list from the after list, then seeing if the after list is not zero. I ran into trouble deleting the before list from the after list. Filenames with square brackets were not being deleted from the list.

```
while read -r LINE                                                              
do                                                                              
        sed -i -- "/$LINE/d" listfilesafter.swp #without the -- I get 'sed: 1: "listfilesafter.swp": extra characters at the end of l command'
        rm listfilesafter.swp--                                                 
done < listfilesbefore.swp
```

If I use '' then the variable doesn't get called, and the -r option on read doesn't seem to make it work like I expected. If anyone has any suggestions on alternative ways of doing this, do contribute, but I would still like to know how to use a variable in the search pattern when the value of the variable contains metacharacters. If anyone can help remove the code smell of "rm listfilesafter.swp--" then that would also be appreciated. Full code below:

```
cd ~/Desktop
ls >listfilesbefore.swp
#echo "balh blah" >SomeNonZeroFile.txt #comment or uncomment to test the if then statement
ls >listfilesafter.swp
sed -i -- '/listfilesafter.swp/d' listfilesafter.swp #deletes listfilesafter.swp from the list of files create after the event on line 3
while read -r LINE
do
        sed -i -- "/$LINE/d" listfilesafter.swp #without the -- I get 'sed: 1: "listfilesafter.swp": extra characters at the end of l command'
        rm listfilesafter.swp--
done < listfilesbefore.swp
cat listfilesafter.swp
echo "check listfiles. Enter to continue."
read dummy_variable
if [ -s listfilesafter.swp ]
then
        rm listfilesbefore.swp
        rm listfilesafter.swp
        echo "success, the file was created"
else
        rm listfilesbefore.swp
        rm listfilesafter.swp
        echo "failure, the file was not created"
fi
```

Comment: you might take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4717415/2082964

Comment: That seems like a contorted way to test whether a file was created.  Why not simply look for the name that was supposed to be created?  (You should use `trap` to ensure that temporary files are removed.  You should also use names for the temporary files such that two people running the script at the same time won't interfere with each other.  For example, use `listfilebefore.$$.swp` to embed the process ID, or use `mktemp` (command) to create the files.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can't check the file name because in my real script it's always different. Good call with the process ID. I will look into `trap` and `mktemp`

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have two lists of files in sorted order (since `ls` lists the files in sorted order), you should probably be using a command like [`diff`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html) or, in this case, 
[`comm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/comm.html) to find the differences between the two lists of files.

If you want to know which file(s) were created, then that's the list of files (lines) in the second file that are not in the first.  With no options, `comm` lists the lines it reads in 3 columns:

- lines in the first file not in the second
- lines in the second file not in the first
- lines in both files

You only need the lines (file names) in the second column, and therefore you want to suppress the list of files in the first and third columns, so you'll use `comm -13` to do that:

```
before=$(mktemp ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/files.XXXXXX)
after=$(mktemp ${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/files.XXXXXX)

trap "rm -f $before $after; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15

ls > $before
…execute command that creates file(s)…
ls > $after
comm -13 $before $after

rm -f $before $after
trap 0
```

Obviously, you could capture the list of files from `comm` in a variable for further analysis, etc.

---

### Making `sed` work when the search strings contain metacharacters

> I'm still confused about sed. How do I use a variable in the search pattern of `sed` if the value contains metacharacters? Or in this case would I be better off using something other than `sed`?

In the scenario you have, you're far better off not using `sed`, and in any case your technique is horrendously slow if there are hundreds or thousands of files in the directory (running `sed` once per file name is not going to be fast).

However, supposing that it was necessary to use `sed` and that you wanted to deal with metacharacters in the file names in the list, then you would have to escape the metacharacters (with a backslash in front).  I'd probably do something like this:

```
sed 's/[][\/*.]/\\&/g; s%.*%/^&$/d%' listfilesbefore.swp > script.sed
sed -f script.sed listfilesafter.swp
```

The first script takes any metacharacters in the line (file name) and replaces it with backslash-metacharacter. In the first substitute, the `[][\/*.]` character class matches square brackets, two types of slashes, stars and dots.  Depending on the predilections of the variant of `sed` you're using, you might need to protect `(){}` with backslashes too, but in POSIX standard `sed`, the `{}` gain metacharacter meaning when prefixed with a backslash, so they're not modified by default.  The second substitute takes the possibly modified line and converts it into a 'match and delete' command.  The output, therefore, is a `sed` script that will delete the file names found in `listfilesbefore.swp`.  The second command applies that script to `listfilesafter.swp`, doing in one `sed` command what your outline code does with one run of `sed` per file name.

Using `sed` to generate a `sed` script is a powerful technique.  It isn't always appropriate, but when it is, it is very useful.

#### Shell script `demo.sh`

```
echo "Pre-populate the directory with some random file names"
for file in $(random -n 20 -T '%W%V%C-%w%v%c%v%c-%04[0000:9999]d.txt')
do
    cp /dev/null $file
done

for template in '%w%v%w(%03[000:999]d)%w%v%w.txt' \
                '%w%v%w[123]%w%v%we.txt' \
                '%w%v%wfile*%03[0:999]d*.txt' \
                '%w%v%w%v%c\\\%d.txt' \
                '%w%v%w-{%04X}-{%04X}.txt'
do
    for file in $(random -n 2 -T "$template")
    do
        cp /dev/null "$file"
    done
done

ls > listfilesbefore.swp
ls

echo
echo "Create some new files with metacharacters in the names"
for file in 'new(123)file.txt' 'new[123]file.txt' 'newfile*321*.txt' \
            'newfile\\\.txt' 'newfile-{A39F}-{B77D}.txt'
do
    cp /dev/null "$file"
done

ls
ls > listfilesafter.swp

echo
echo "Create sed script"

sed 's/[][\/*.]/\\&/g; s%.*%/^&$/d%' listfilesbefore.swp > script.sed

echo
cat script.sed

echo
echo "Apply it"
sed -f script.sed listfilesafter.swp
```

The `random` command I'm using is of my own devising, but it is convenient for demonstrations such as this.

#### Example run

```
Pre-populate the directory with some random file names
AIG-taral-3486.txt
COV-oipuc-9088.txt
CUG-vowan-5758.txt
FEH-ieqek-0603.txt
IUS-aaduw-7080.txt
KER-jazuc-4824.txt
MIZ-iezec-8255.txt
NIT-kupib-6873.txt
PUX-oocov-2216.txt
QAW-xonod-3937.txt
QES-wawok-4790.txt
RON-difag-1986.txt
SAD-gesug-5706.txt
SAJ-luqoj-4311.txt
TUZ-wapaw-8547.txt
VAL-zutap-8054.txt
YIP-xudeb-7397.txt
YUP-uudiv-8848.txt
ZIB-jurax-2903.txt
ZUR-xonik-8800.txt
aavfile*147*.txt
demo.sh
diman\\\7115.txt
ganur\\\8732.txt
gud-{7049}-{3103}.txt
listfilesbefore.swp
lur[123]maee.txt
rivfile*065*.txt
ueo(417)yea.txt
uoi(751)qio.txt
woi-{37E8}-{009C}.txt
xof[123]hoxe.txt

Create some new files with metacharacters in the names
AIG-taral-3486.txt
COV-oipuc-9088.txt
CUG-vowan-5758.txt
FEH-ieqek-0603.txt
IUS-aaduw-7080.txt
KER-jazuc-4824.txt
MIZ-iezec-8255.txt
NIT-kupib-6873.txt
PUX-oocov-2216.txt
QAW-xonod-3937.txt
QES-wawok-4790.txt
RON-difag-1986.txt
SAD-gesug-5706.txt
SAJ-luqoj-4311.txt
TUZ-wapaw-8547.txt
VAL-zutap-8054.txt
YIP-xudeb-7397.txt
YUP-uudiv-8848.txt
ZIB-jurax-2903.txt
ZUR-xonik-8800.txt
aavfile*147*.txt
demo.sh
diman\\\7115.txt
ganur\\\8732.txt
gud-{7049}-{3103}.txt
listfilesbefore.swp
lur[123]maee.txt
new(123)file.txt
new[123]file.txt
newfile*321*.txt
newfile-{A39F}-{B77D}.txt
newfile\\\.txt
rivfile*065*.txt
ueo(417)yea.txt
uoi(751)qio.txt
woi-{37E8}-{009C}.txt
xof[123]hoxe.txt

Create sed script

/^AIG-taral-3486\.txt$/d
/^COV-oipuc-9088\.txt$/d
/^CUG-vowan-5758\.txt$/d
/^FEH-ieqek-0603\.txt$/d
/^IUS-aaduw-7080\.txt$/d
/^KER-jazuc-4824\.txt$/d
/^MIZ-iezec-8255\.txt$/d
/^NIT-kupib-6873\.txt$/d
/^PUX-oocov-2216\.txt$/d
/^QAW-xonod-3937\.txt$/d
/^QES-wawok-4790\.txt$/d
/^RON-difag-1986\.txt$/d
/^SAD-gesug-5706\.txt$/d
/^SAJ-luqoj-4311\.txt$/d
/^TUZ-wapaw-8547\.txt$/d
/^VAL-zutap-8054\.txt$/d
/^YIP-xudeb-7397\.txt$/d
/^YUP-uudiv-8848\.txt$/d
/^ZIB-jurax-2903\.txt$/d
/^ZUR-xonik-8800\.txt$/d
/^aavfile\*147\*\.txt$/d
/^demo\.sh$/d
/^diman\\\\\\7115\.txt$/d
/^ganur\\\\\\8732\.txt$/d
/^gud-{7049}-{3103}\.txt$/d
/^listfilesbefore\.swp$/d
/^lur\[123\]maee\.txt$/d
/^rivfile\*065\*\.txt$/d
/^ueo(417)yea\.txt$/d
/^uoi(751)qio\.txt$/d
/^woi-{37E8}-{009C}\.txt$/d
/^xof\[123\]hoxe\.txt$/d

Apply it
listfilesafter.swp
new(123)file.txt
new[123]file.txt
newfile*321*.txt
newfile-{A39F}-{B77D}.txt
newfile\\\.txt
```

Comment: Very useful answer, but I'm still confused about sed. How do I use a variable in the search pattern of sed if the value contains metacharacters? Or in this case would I be better off using something other than sed?