# List all files in git repo not added by `git annex add`

Tags: git, git-annex

Is there a way to list all files I added via `git add` (ref 1) and not by `git annex add` (ref 2)?

```sh
mkdir myrepo
cd myrepo
git init .
mkdir foo
dd if=/dev/random of=foo/bar.ext count=1024 bs=1024
git add foo   # <----- ref 1   
git commit -m "add foo"
```

```sh
git annex init "listing"
mkdir baz
dd if=/dev/random of=baz/abc.ext count=1024 bs=1024
dd if=/dev/random of=baz/efg.ext count=2024 bs=1024
dd if=/dev/random of=baz/xyz.ext count=512 bs=1024
git annex add baz    # <---- ref 2
git commit -m "add baz"
```

So when I run `git <some command>` it should show something like

```
foo/bar.ext
```

One of the solutions I used is https://stackoverflow.com/a/61680771/7274758 . But I am wondering if there is any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `ls-files` to list all files in repo.
2. Use `annex find` to list all files in annex.
3. Find the [unique entries from the above results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4717415/7274758)

```sh
git ls-files > ~/tmp/ls-files.list
git annex find > ~/tmp/annex-find.list
awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++; next} !a[$0]' ~/tmp/annex-find.list ~/tmp/ls-files.list
```

Comment: You can also add this one-liner to your git config file: `awk 'FNR==NR {a[$0]++; next} !a[$0]' <(git annex find) <(git ls-files)` and if the number files is really large, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204904/fast-way-of-finding-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another) on fast alternatives to that awk script.